# Why does RestKit save all NSManagedObjectContexts via performBlockAndWait?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I noticed that when saving `NSManagedObjectContexts`, RestKit wraps the `save` call on each `NSManagedObjectContext` with a `performBlockAndWait`.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/CoreData/NSManagedObjectContext%2BRKAdditions.m#L64

It was my understanding of managing parent and child `NSManagedObjectContexts` that only a `NSManagedObjectContext` with type `MainQueueConcurrencyType` should be saved this way (and that is usually the child context of another `NSManagedObjectContext` of type `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` which is what is actually associated with `persistentStoreCoordinator`).  I thought that the idea was that saving to the persistent store (ie disk) is a longer operation and doesn't, and shouldn't, be waited for.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do with a ManagedObjectContext has to be done on that context's dispatch queue. The easiest way to make sure that happens is to do it in a block called by performBlock or performBlockAndWait. If there is code later in the method depending on the result of the block, performBlockAndWait is the way to go. If you have to add these blocks to older Core Data code, as in the case of RestKit, wrapping NSManagedObjectContext calls in a performBlockAndWait is a not-too-painful way to make your Core Data code (more) thread-safe.